# Pycozmo cube tapped?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a small game with Cozmo, using the PyCozmo library. When you tap a cube Cozmo tells you a random number. Is there an event in PyCozmo that turns True if a cube it pressed? For example:

```
def on_cube_press(cube_id):
    if pycozmo.cube_pressed(cube_id) == True:
         return True
```

my full code is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pycozmo
import time

dozmo = pycozmo.Client()
dozmo.start()
dozmo.connect()
dozmo.wait_for_robot()

dozmo.drive_wheels(lwheel_speed = 50.0, rwheel_speed = 50.0, duration = 2.0)

dozmo.set_lift_height(92)

def on_cube_tap(cli, pkt: pycozmo.protocol_encoder.ObjectTapped):
    print("cube tapped.")



dozmo.add_handler(pycozmo.protocol_encoder.ObjectTapped, on_cube_tap)

#stop
dozmo.disconnect()
dozmo.stop()
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://pycozmo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/external/functions.html#cube-accelerometers) says: "the robot performs basic cube accelerometer ata processing and provides basic events with the following messages: " and there's a relevant message: `ObjectTapped`. Have you looked into that event?

Comment: Yes I have, it is not very clear how I can implement it.

Comment: Their [events example](https://github.com/zayfod/pycozmo/blob/master/examples/events.py) makes it look quite straightforward, what about the implementation is confusing you?

Comment: I have tried def on_cube_tap(cli, pkt: pycozmo.protocol_encoder.ObjectTapped):
    print("cube tapped."). I have replaced a different event with this new one, I need to get the cube to connect too.

Comment: Please put all relevant code in your post, not as a comment. Please include the part where you added the event handler via `add_handler`, too.

Comment: I have edited my post to include my code :) hope it helps

Comment: Does the cube connecting code in this example help? https://github.com/zayfod/pycozmo/blob/master/examples/cube_light_animation.py

Comment: Yes!, how can I give the `add_handler` the cube id and other stuff

Comment: I don't actually know, I'm not familiar with the library at all. I think if nobody else answers and you can't figure it out while playing around, you might try finding another place to ask. You can also always ask the developer for an example. And, the GitHub page has a discussions area which could help too: https://github.com/zayfod/pycozmo/discussions

Comment: Ok I will do that! should I mark this post answered

Comment: If you figure it out, you can post the answer here and accept it, but otherwise the question will remain open for others to potentially answer, which is fine.